# Linear algebra as a gauge theory

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, gauge-theory, linear-algebra

Is linear algebra a gauge theory? Is the gauge transformation a change of basis?

This was the explanation that I received:

> "Take the principal bundle to be the frame bundle $LM$ of your space $M$. Then, have an associated vector bundle. Then elements of (the total space of) that vector bundle are your "abstract vectors" from linear algebra, and the typical fiber of it is your "coordinate vectors" from linear algebra.
>
> Simply: Linear algebra has a change of basis symmetry."

I am not sure if I understand what this means. It would be helpful if someone could explain.

Comment: which ones would be the theory equations that remain unchanged under change in coordinates? plus not every symmetry is a gauge symmetry

Answer (score 3):

The claim that linear algebra is a gauge theory doesn't even make sense to me.  It's like saying that calculus is a Lagrangian theory.  However, one can frame a general gauge theory as a manifestation of basis independence for each fiber of a vector bundle associated to some principal bundle or another. In that sense, the claim is backward, if anything.

I suppose if you're willing to imagine that $M$ can be a single point, so the vector bundle is just a single fiber, then you could say that the gauge theory reduces to elementary linear algebra in some sense.  However, to me that's like using billions of transistors to build a computer, then programming the computer to act like a single transistor and claiming that transistors are made of computers.

Answer (score 2):

No. Linear Algebra (LA) is not a gauge theory. LA is a field of mathematics,
whereas a gauge theory is a field in physics.

In a large sense one can say that gauge theories contain the concept of ${{ local}}$ gauge transformations. However, in Linear Algebra the transformations are all global, they cover the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

A change of basis in the **vector space**  is rather a global transformation, because it transforms each vector by multiplication by the same matrix.

What the quote is speaking about resembles much more a notion of local coordinate frame and the **vierbein formalism** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_fields_in_general_relativity).

With each point in space there is an associated a frame built of coordinate basis vector fields on the manifold $\mathcal{M}$. The natural basis is spanned by the vectors in the tangent space $T \mathcal{M}$:
$$\vec{X} = X^\mu \partial_\mu
$$
where $\partial_\mu$ are some basis vectors in tangent space.

One can choose the basis $e_{(a)}$at each point $p$ independently of the chosen system of coordinates, the only requirement is to respect the signature of the manifold. For example, if one is working in Minkowskian manifold, basis can be chosen to be orthonormal:
$$
(e_{(a)}, e_{(b)}) = \eta_{ab}
$$
Where $ \eta_{ab}$ is a Minkowski metric $(1 -1 -1 -1)$.

There is no unique for the choice of the local basis at each point. Possible choices, preserving the signature of the metric, are related by **Local Lorentz transformations** :
$$
e_{(a^{'})} = \Lambda_{(a^{'})}^{a} e_{(a)}
$$
Where $\Lambda_{(a^{'})}^{a}$ is matrix from $SO(1,3)$:
$$
\eta_{ab} \Lambda_{(a^{'})}^{a}  \Lambda_{(b^{'})}^{b} = \eta_{a^{'} b^{'}}
$$